# Referencing a file local to a Python File

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have been experimenting with the Python Cloud Functions. One of my cloud functions utlizies a large text file, that I would love to bundle with my .py file when I deploy it. THe docs are kinda limited on stuff like this..

https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/quickstart

I was looking, would I just include that file, and a requirements file in my  same directory as my function to deploy it. Or do I have to some how require it in my code?

Also, is there any information on how to use a database trigger instead of a http trigger? I was trying to think if the reason my file didn't seem to get included was because I had the wrong way of defining the trigger. How would you create an OnCreate.. or something like that

```
gcloud beta functions deploy hello_get --runtime python37 --trigger-http
```

Comment: Triggers on Firebase products are not currently supported for python.  You have to write those in JavaScript or TypeScript targeting node.js.

Comment: @Doug must be really new then.. in google cloud console you can create them for firebase products

Answer (score 2):

When you deploy your function using `gcloud`, your project directory is zipped and uploaded. Any files contained in the current directory (and child directories) will be uploaded as well, which includes static assets like your large text file.

Just make sure your text file is in your project directory (or one of the child directories), then use a relative reference to your file in your Python code. It should just work.